# Typescript and type inference: issue with validation

Tags: typescript, types

I currently have a function that does something similar to this (I wrote a minimal-working example for the sake of the discussion):

```
interface Variable {
  someMethod: () => void
}

const validateVariable(variable: Variable | undefined) {
  if(!variable) {
    throw new Error('Variable is undefined!')
  }
}

const doSomething = async (): void => { 
  // maybeGetSomething returns a Variable or undefined
  // depends on the database, so both cases are definitely possible
  const variable: (Variable | undefined) = await maybeGetSomething()

  validateVariable(variable)

  variable.someMethod()
}
```

but Typescript complains that `variable` might be undefined. I don't like the idea of putting the code of `validateVariable` in `doSomething` because in my case the validation is a non-trivial function I need to be able to re-use. It also feels stupid to define a new variable just so that Typescript doesn't complain about its type, since after validation it can only have the Variable type anyway (code can't make it through the line with `validateVariable(variable)` unless it hasn't thrown, in which case the variable has the appropriate type).

What would be a good way of doing this? I'm open to changing the structure of my code since I am still learning a lot about Typescript, I am flexible about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By giving `validateVariable` a special return type, you can tell typescript that if the function returns (as opposed to throwing), then the variable must be defined:

```
function validateVariable(variable: Variable | undefined): asserts variable is Variable {
  if(!variable) {
    throw new Error('Variable is undefined!')
  }
}
```

If you do that, then after you call `validateVariable(variable)` the type on `variable` will be narrowed to just `Variable`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpysOAjANigbwChlkBnAewFsIBZCMACwoBMAuZACgEpkBeAHzIAbhWAsiAXyJEEFEGTDIqcAJ7YIAcQYBlag0agA5v2RwyqkAi7cOABSjVgZCAB50mHPmQAfZAFcQFggYUAgWIUFkYlIoBn8oEACgkLCWAG4pGRhAhDBgeRE4XHE4SA8sPAhOYQxK-A4KrxQ-QODQkHDbMzIXKDAyIs8q5Gc0OuboklGYTgBCWuH8XhjSZCZHAHdkTu2AUShHKE4AciaRsbbUzpY5k%205p6WlZeUVkFgo9GiZjU3NLaw8fhCAjIaYAenByjUGm0YC%20Bl%20cTACQUZnGSxQFCgyXaaQhUOCAAcIEFBoUmCgWGUcOYIAAacgUZDYChMZAIOmDDBU67ASC4VTIIkUXrAKrTOQKJSLeoQDicc7eVopDpdP6bOD86HqLS6fQ-EBGHgyUi1ErU8oTKo1a3LU1DOUAOkoNHoTFYJskQA)

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I want! I tried to implement it in my repository though, and I get this: 
`Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation.`
What am I missing?

Comment: I looked around and it seems related to the fact that my `validateVariable` function was built as an arrow function. I can work around that (wasn't using "this" there anyway), but is there a good reason why it doesn't work with arrow functions but it does with the `function` keyword?

Comment: Unfortunately this feature doesn't seem to be available until Typescript 3.7 and our repository is still on Typescript 3.6.3, so I can't use this. It seems to be the right way to do it though. I'll give you the green check, and let me know if you have a better option than mine for Typescript <= 3.6.3!

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html